# Magento 2 - custom validator before order placement

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation

I would like to add a custom validator before oder placement.
The validor will check if the customer has a default shipping and billing address before to validate the order. If the customer hasn't default billing ans shipping address, I would like to put the address of the order to the default addresses of this customer.

I did a DefaultAddress.js in /app/code/Vendor_Name/Module_Name/DefaultAddress/view/frontend/web/js/model

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'mage/validation',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list'
],
function (Component, additionalValidators, quote, customer, addressList) {
    'use strict';

    return {

        /**
         * Validate checkout agreements
         *
         * @returns {Boolean}
         */
        validate: function () {
            var defaultShippingAddress = false;
            var defaultBillingAddress = false;

            if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                // CHECK IF CUSTOMER HAS DEFAULT BILLING / SHIPPING ADDRESS
                    // IF NO , ADD QUOTE ADDRESSES ON CUSTOMER ACCOUNT
                        // --> Return true to validate the order

                    // IF YES , RETURN true to validate the order
            }
        }
    };
}
```

);

Can you help me ?